# Please vote to re-open this question about assault at company Christmas party

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I have significantly improved [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104539/king-hit-by-coworker-at-christmas-party) by doing the following:

1. Revised title and remove country / region specific slang (e.g: King hit in Australia)
2. Added the country tag of Australia based on the slang "King Hit"
3. Removed language not pertinent to the core question of the OP - speculating reason for the coworker assaulting the OP.
4. Clarified question of the OP to be work-place focused to avoid rant.

**Could this community please vote to re-open this question?** I would like to answer once it is re-opened, expanding on a good start by @ Glen Pierce.

Comment: This question your referencing is one delete vote from being gone.

Comment: I don't see how removing country-specific slang is an "improvement". This is an international community, and there is no requirement that every question should be understood by everybody.

Answer (score 5):

It may be cleaned up but still should be closed.

When into shock and then told to leave for bleeding.  No responsible bar would do that.

Bouncers over the assailant when he went outside.  No responsible bar would do that.

Punched just for shaking someones hand?

This is just not believable.

Comment: I would add there is no tangible answer regarding his work. He should let the police handle the problem and if a second one happens at work, he should show the evidence to HR.

Comment: I agree with all the points.